# Keep query string while reload AngularJS page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I would like to keep some query string on my url after click(and refresh the page

I'm using:

```
$state.reload();
```

but its not keep the url quertytring I have button on the page  and after click from "buttonControler" I just want to refresh the page and but the url should open with `url.com/buttonPage/?param1&param2`

I also tried:

```
var url = $location.absUrl().split('?')[0];
$window.location.href = url +"?param"
```

... but this is the same url basically and it is not make a refresh, cause after refresh I got a new data.

Comment: Please add your UI-router configuration & the full route you clicking.

Comment: @lin updated the question . - just want to refresh the page and keep the querystring

Comment: Please check my answer, this sould work for you.

Answer (score 0):

This should work with `$state.reload()` if you configured your state params in your route which is reloaded. `$state.reload()` is the equivalent to:

```
$state.transitionTo($state.current, $stateParams, {
    reload: true,
    inherit: false,
    notify: true
});
```

In that way if your route is `url.com/buttonPage/?param1=var&param2=var2` your state define should look like:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('buttonPage', {
       url: '/buttonPage',
       params: {
          param1: null,
          param2: null
       },
       templateUrl: 'someTemplate.html
     })
```

For more information about handling params in routes pleace check the [UI-router routing documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing).